# package docker-ce requires containerd.io >= 1.4.1, but none of the providers can be installed

Tags: docker, redhat, yum, containerd

I had this problem this morning for both update / upgrade on red hat (Linux 4.18.0-240.1.1.el8_3.x86_64), not sure what to do. Sounds like yum is completely stuck because of this.

```
$ sudo yum update
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Last metadata expiration check: 2:40:27 ago on Wed 16 Dec 2020 07:53:10 AM CST.
Error: 
 Problem: package docker-ce-3:20.10.1-3.el7.x86_64 requires containerd.io >= 1.4.1, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package docker-ce-3:19.03.14-3.el7.x86_64
  - package containerd.io-1.4.3-3.1.el7.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to install packages built for EL 7 on EL 8. This isn't going to work, and it's not clear how you managed to do that in the first place. The [correct Docker CE repo file](https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo) gets the correct package versions for your RHEL release, and you should use it instead of whatever custom repo you have used.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
```

And then:

```
sudo yum update
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install on CentOS8
sudo yum update -y
sudo yum-config-manager 
--add-repo 
https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo

Install Docker CE:
sudo yum -y install docker-ce --allowerasing

Answer (score -2):

Go here https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7/x86_64/nightly/Packages/ find the package dnf is asking for install it manually the run dnf update. it will work with out any issues.

Comment: He is running RHEL 8, not RHEL 7. These packages will not work.

Comment: yes it will I have to do it.

Comment: Linux nuc 4.18.0-240.1.1.el8_3.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Nov 19 17:20:08 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@nuc blah]# rpm -i containerd.io-1.4.3-3.1.el7.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
 containerd conflicts with containerd.io-1.4.3-3.1.el7.x86_64
 runc conflicts with containerd.io-1.4.3-3.1.el7.x86_64
 containerd conflicts with (installed) containerd.io-1.4.3-3.1.el7.x86_64
 runc conflicts with (installed) containerd.io-1.4.3-3.1.el7.x86_64

Comment: I works fine he needs it to run docker on 8 with out using pacman. Dnf will hang if you don't do it this way.